# ?? or .GetValueOrDefault()

Tags: c#, .net, operators, null-coalescing

I have properties type `int?` and `decimal?` that are being used in a calculation. If the value of any of them is null it has to default to 0. I'm trying to decide between using null-coalescing or `GetValueOrDefault()` which will also default to 0 if a value is `null`.
Which approach would be better in terms of readability and performance (if there is any noticeable difference)?

First:

```
public decimal MyMethod(int memberId)
{ 
    var dto = GetDtoValue(memberId);
 return (dto.PropertyOne ?? 0)
      + (dto.PropertyTwo ?? 0)
      + (dto.PropertyThree ?? 0)
      - (dto.PropertyFour ?? 0)
      + ...
}
```

Second:

```
public decimal MyMethod(int memberId)
    { 
        var dto = GetDtoValue(memberId);
     return dto.PropertyOne.GetValueOrDefault())
          + dto.PropertyTwo.GetValueOrDefault())
          + dto.PropertyThree.GetValueOrDefault())
          - dto.PropertyFour.GetValueOrDefault())
          + ...
    }
```

Comment: Define what counts as “better” to you. I’d use ?? for clutter reasons, some may prefer the express readability of GVOD

Comment: "better" would be code appearance/readability and performance (if there is any noticeable difference)

Comment: The first seems to be easier to read imho.

Comment: I’m afraid this question is largely off topic for SO as it’s “primarily opinion based” being essentially “which of these looks better?”

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right, I personally think the top one looks better :-)

Comment: I don't like that this question was closed.  For example you can objectively answer which option is faster (if there is a difference) or answer that there do the same stuff, there is no difference and they compile to the same code. 

I think questions like "I can do a thing in two ways, what is better" is fine, if you think it's opinion base then think of it as if person asked "I can do a thing in two ways, what is the difference between them". Because this is what the question is really about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Readability

This is opinion of course, but

- I read `?? 0` and feel like it's clear immediately
- I read `GetValueOrDefault` and have to take a second to think about the type and then that type's default value (and I don't see this as a problem, just pointing out the "mental mapping")

#### Performance

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-fastest-null-coalescing-operator-vs-getvalue) holds that `GetValueOrDefault` compiles to CIL that's technically faster, but the improvement is a [micro-optimization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) at best.

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIIwDZMCZ0BhLdAbwFgAodWzDbPMAO2HQBUBTAZ2AAoWwAPzoAbgEpqdaegC8APjHohQgAwBuagF9q1NJlwFihSjTr7G6QRx79BIiVJm0FYgHQBxTsABqAQwgAV04AeQAnABFOADM/QIh+cU0qLSA=), however, has both versions compiling to the exact same CIL (via [Marc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437217/or-getvalueordefault#comment112546231_56437378)), which would make their performance identical.

Either way, the performance difference is insignificant at best, and nonexistent at worst, which means that **readability should be prioritized**.

Comment: There is no performance difference - see: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIIwDZMCZ0BhdAbwFgAodGzDbPMAO2HQBUBTAZ2AApngAfnQA3AJRVaU9AF4AfKPSDBABgDcVAL5A=

Answer (score 3):

`??` (null coalesce) will call `GetValueOrDefault` internally in this situation.

The performance difference will be insignificant (unless you have a performance problem), so all that's left is working out which way you think is more readable.

Check it out [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1N+BARgPaMQECGAzjOgBRMsB+AgCcAlFRrVK2SbOQB2EQDoA4gFNgANTYQArmoDywgCJqAZm10RgPUQG4JkgL6PZ1Ov1acYqPswhCYq5SwZIKIgQCQsDC+g4ysi4J7oTIACwEALK2FKHu6ACcPN68AHZWEKL2eUSFxVy+5RCV1cmyrklOQA===).

Comment: I’m interested to know more about how the compiler knows to rewrite this as GVOD? I’d always assumed it was rewritten as an inline-if null check

Comment: @CaiusJard note this is less to do with Null Coalesce and more to do with Nullable Types as they are a special case in the language in all sorts of ways, they are also an implementation detail.

Comment: Perhaps a better example: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIIwDZMCZ0BhdAbwFgAodGzDbPMAO2HQBUBTAZ2AApngAfnQA3AJRVaU9AF4AfKPSDBABgDcVAL5A=